# How to create a new rewrite rule for an buddy press profile page

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, buddypress

I have an existing buddy press user profile link: e.g. https://example.com/members/joseph-bada

I need to make https://example.com/members/joseph-b an exact duplicate of it.

this my code simplified version:

```
add_filter('wp', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $slug = $wp_query->query_vars['name'];
    if($slug==='joseph-bada') {
        add_rewrite_rule('^members/joseph-b/?', 'members/joseph-bada', 'top');
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}
```

but if i browse https://example.com/members/joseph-b - i get 404 error

UPDATE:
even after adding this in functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'custom_test');
function custom_test() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_rule('^members/joseph-b', 'members/joseph-bada', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

https://example.com/members/joseph-b is still 404

can someone please point out what im missing?

UPDATE: i learned that https://example.com/index.php?bbp_user=joseph-bada&edit=1
leads to https://example.com/members/joseph-bada

so now i tried this:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_test');
function custom_test() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_rule('^members/joseph-b', 'https://example.com/index.php?bbp_user=joseph-bada&edit=1', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

still no avail 404 though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i gave up using add_rewrite_rule wordpress functionality.. instead, i studied buddypress plugin and how it works.. i discovered the following filters:

```
function custom_bp_domain_filter($domain, $user_id) {
    $change_slug = is_joseph_bada_user_id($user_id);
    if ($change_slug) {
        $domain = trailingslashit(bp_get_root_domain() . '/' . 'members/joseph-b');
    }
    return $domain;
}

add_filter('bp_core_get_user_domain', 'custom_bp_domain_filter', 10, 2);
```

this part above is a filter wherein im gonna check if the user id being displayed belongs to members/joseph-bada. if it is, change it to members/joseph-b

```
function custom_bp_after_slug_filter($after_member_slug) {

    if ($after_member_slug==='joseph-b') {
        $after_member_slug = 'joseph-bada';
    }
    return $after_member_slug;
}

add_filter('bp_core_set_uri_globals_member_slug', 'custom_bp_after_slug_filter');
```

this above part determines if the URI is now members/joseph-b.. we dont have a user with that, instead it is 'joseph-bada'

the returned value here is the user to be displayed so we need to return 'joseph-bada' if the param value is 'joseph-b'

when members/joseph-b is browsed.. it will display the profile of members/joseph-bada

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a WP developer, but here goes.

It looks as though the $query part of the add_rewrite_rule needs to be explicit in its setting (as shown in the below example with the index.php string).

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/?([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I also notice that you are doing an add_filter as opposed to add_action.